# invalid type character for column using the daisy function in R

Tags: r, distance-matrix, r-daisy

```
gower_dist <- daisy(vechiles[, -1],
                    metric = "gower",
                    type = list(logratio = 3))
```

I'm trying to run this function on my data set, but I keep getting `invalid type character for column` as an error, it's clear this error is caused due to some columns being non-numeric, but how do I fix this? I tried running a solution I found on a similar question on Stack Overflow.

```
df$drive <- as.factor(df$drive)
```

but this didn't seem to fix my problem. The same error kept popping up. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't trust conversion of string to `factor` to count as "numeric", for several reasons: (1) many functions know the difference between integers and the ints stored in a `factor`, so you cannot trick them; more importantly to me, (2) the integers imply *ordinality*, and in distance calcs, the ints can be confused for continuous values, which is almost certainly inappropriate with `factor`s.

Comment: Suggestion: run `str(vechiles)` and find which columns show a class other than `int` and `num`. Or if you don't want to know that much about your data, use `vechiles[,sapply(vechiles, inherits, "numeric")]`. (I urge you to "know" your data, and use exactly the columns you intend to use.)

Comment: how would you suggest i fix this issue? i tried using as.numeric(df$drive). but i get the following error.  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Without seeing any sample data, I really don't know how to help. Please [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(head(vechiles))`.

Comment: @r2evans output is huge, i cant possibly fit that into the question, but it consists of structure(list(barrels08 = c(15.6957142857143, 29.9645454545455, 
12.2077777777778, 29.9645454545455, 17.3478947368421, 14.9822727272727
), barrelsA08 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), charge120 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), charge240 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), city08 = c(19L, 9L, 23L, 
10L, 17L, 21L), city08U = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cityA08 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), cityA08U = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cityCD = c(0, 

-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L), co2TailpipeAGpm

Comment: @r2evans some dates also, i guess my best bet would be to just remove these columns, any suggestions on how i can do that, thanks

Comment: Comments are really bad for data/code, as I suggested before please [edit] your question and include the full output from `dput(head(vechiles))` in a code block. Understand that I'm not asking for something frivolous: often (esp to newer users), one can assume that data that looks like a number or a date whereas it is really a `factor` or string. `dput` is one way to provide an unambiguous look at the data, not otherwise possible with simple console output or such. `str` is also unambiguous, but it is not in a form that we can just "use", where `dput` is.

Comment: @r2evans yes i understand, but as mentioned previously i cannot post the output, the website simply doesnt allow me. i cannot exceed a certain amount of characters. i can only post less than a quarter of the output, but im not sure that helps since a lot of data would be missing. could you suggest a way to remove these columns? i can drop each one, but that would take a lot of lines of code. maybe a better solution would be better

Comment: Can you post `str(vechiles)`? From the bit you did post it looks like the first 6 values of the third variable is `charge120 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`. Your code says to take the logarithm of those values (`type = list(logratio = 3)`) which is impossible since the `log(0)` is undefined (-Inf).